# Отследить неактивность мыши в течение времени

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задача в том, чтобы произвести действие после того, как пользователь не двигал мышку в течение 10 секунд. Пробовал делать так:

```
let timeout;
const eventHandlerHiddenElement = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => alert("Move stop!"), 10000);
}

<div onMouseMove={() => eventHandlerHiddenElement()}>
    content
</div>
```

Но alert срабатывает много раз после остановки. Как правильно реализовать эту задачу?

Comment: добавить какой-то флаг, что хэндлер сработал, чтобы не срабатывало.

Comment: А вам обязательно, чтобы это был alert? Потому что например console.log отрабатывает только один раз

Comment: console.log тоже срабатывает несколько раз после остановки мыши

Comment: Все разобрался. Может кому-то пригодится -> let timeout вынес в useState и все работает корректно.